# How to join 2 model with relation when using Yii CActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to export data to excel using 2 models. `HasilPutusan model and DetilSaksi model.`

When I used the CActiveDataProvider with Model **HasilPutusan**, I managed to get all the data together with the data relationships that are interrelated with this HasilPutusan models.

And how do I combine the data both by using Model **DetilSaksi**?

My controller :

```
public function actionCetakjalanperistiwa()
{
    if(isset($_POST['PrintJaper'])){
        $data = $_POST['id_kecelakaan'];
        if($data==''){
            return false;
        }else{
            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('HasilPutusan', array(
                'criteria'=>array(
                    'condition'=>'id_kecelakaan=:id',
                    'params'=>array(':id'=>$data),
                ),
            ));
        }
        $this->widget('ext.EExcelView', array(
            'grid_mode'=>'export',
            'title' => 'Data Jalan Peristiwa',
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'exportType'=>'Excel2007',
            'columns'=>array(
                'id_hasil_putusan',
                'id_detil',
                'id_kapal',
                'idKapal.nama_kapal',
                'idKapal.tahun_pembuatan',
                'idKapal.konstruksi',
                'idKapal.isi_kotor',
                'idKapal.tenaga_penggerak_utama',
                'idKapal.pemilik',
                'idKapal.nakhoda',
                'idKapal.awak_kapal',
                'idKapal.surat_kapal',
            ),
        ));
    }else{
        $this->render('_japer');    
    }
}
```

In my tbl_hasil_putusan table, i have a **id_detil** field which I will use to re-do the query to the second table using the DetilSaksi model.

My database :
[image]

[image]

How do I combine the two tables that can be joined so that I can call related (**blue arrow**) data in the second table?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the relation to DetilSaksi specified in the relations method of the HasilPutusan model?

Comment: No. I will check with query the same data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join in the criteria array. Something like this:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('HasilPutusan', array(
'criteria'=>array(
    'condition'=>'id_kecelakaan=:id',
    'select' => 't.*, ds.*'
    'join' => 'LEFT JOIN tbl_detil_saksi ds on ds.id_detil = t.id_detil',
    'params'=>array(
        ':id'=>$data),
     ),
));
```

Comment: But how i get a `id_saksi` data in 'columns'=>array ?

Comment: Try renoving the * column selector, and use column alias, eg, 'select' => 'ds.id_saksi as my_id_saksi*'